# JPA on many to many and authority list

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many

I have a many to many relation Person - Preferences(this is in principle an authority list).

The mapping table is person_has_preferences.
My goal is to add a new object in Person table without adding the object in Preferences.
At the current configuration all the 3 table are updated.

Here's my object configuration:

Person:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "person_has_preference", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", nullable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "preference_id", nullable = false) })
private List<Preference> preferences = new ArrayList<Preference>();
```

Preference:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "person_has_preference", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "preference_id", nullable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", nullable = false) })
private List<Person> persons;
```

The persistance is done here:

```
EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    if (em.find(Person.class, c.getId()) == null)
        em.persist(c);// new contact
    else
        em.merge(c);// update existing contact

    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

I also noticed that, even if the object Preference exists(has an ID), JPA always create a new ID.
Log:

[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-08-01 10:22:58.244--ClientSession(2012226930)--Connection(583259044)--Thread(Thread[615154846@qtp-1915686435-7,5,main])--INSERT INTO preference (NAME, parent, types) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [Weekly update, null, 1]
[EL Finest]: query: 2013-08-01 10:22:58.248--ClientSession(2012226930)--Thread(Thread[615154846@qtp-1915686435-7,5,main])--Execute query ValueReadQuery(name="SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY" sql="SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-08-01 10:22:58.25--ClientSession(2012226930)--Connection(583259044)--Thread(Thread[615154846@qtp-1915686435-7,5,main])--SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2013-08-01 10:22:58.253--UnitOfWork(925539554)--Thread(Thread[615154846@qtp-1915686435-7,5,main])--assign sequence to the object (126 -> org.icg.contacts.manager.shared.jpa.Preference@19eed47)

Comment: Also the title says something about authority but you're not mentioning it elsewhere, are you talking about spring security and GrantedAuthority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using CascadeType.ALL which enables insertion. Change your CascadeType to your needs  like CascadeType.REFRESH or CascadeType.REMOVE etc.

Simple explanation of each Cascade options: http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/CascadeType